# ReactJS Error Function syntax

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How would the following condition be written using arrow function syntax?

```
var found = array1.find(function(element) {
  return element > 10;
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const found = array1.find((element) => {
  return element > 10;
});
```

Comment: Thank you! ...I  appreciate the quick response

Answer (score 0):

```
let newArray = array1.filter(element => element >10 );
```

Check out the api for `Array.filter` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)